# XWiki livetable EvalError: call to eval() blocked by CSP

Tags: javascript, src, xwiki, content-security-policy

Does anyone know something XWiki and livetables? I allways get an error calls "Uncaught EvalError: call to eval() blocked by CSP" which refers to a livetable.js. I have know idea, how to fix this problem.
I'm not a developer who might know something about.

Livetable can't load enviroment.
Where looking for erros on website.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the livetable page is standard or if it's a custom one (i.e. trying to execute some custom JavaScript code). If custom, then you'd have to check with its author to see what they are trying to do that might be restricted by the CSP (JavaScript security) rules in place.